# The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.prepareStatement(String, int) has not been completed and should not be called

Tags: spring-data, sybase, identity

Why do we get below error on

```
reportRepository.save(report);

        The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.prepareStatement(String, int) 
has not been completed and should not be called
```

I have below table in Sybase. I am using JPA CRUD repository to do DB operations.

```
CREATE TABLE Report (
report_id int identity,
file_name VARCHAR(50)
}
```

Below is my entity class.

```
@Column(name = "report_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long reportId;

@Id
@Column(name = "file_name")
String fileName = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I used to get the same error in my project.

I used to have a `<property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` in my cfg file and for the unique identifier, I had `<generator class="native"></generator>`  .

The reason for the error is that, native confoguration for generator class automatically generates unique identifier for each of the rows.This has compatibility issues with Sybase (I guess). I changed generator class to "*increment*" and enabled the `set identity_insert table_name on` . on the table

It worked fine for me without any errors. Please try this from your end.

Refer the below links

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#portability-idgen

http://www.javatpoint.com/generator-classes